# How do I compile further libraries into my game?

Tags: c++, sdl

This might be vague; I don't know how to search for this.

How do I link a GUI framework (in my case, CEGUI) to a graphics framework (in my case, SDL)?

I'm using a Mac. My mental model on how to add libraries is something like this in my head:

> There are `.framework` files. They go in `/Library/Framework/`. You then link them to Xcode in build settings, then they magically work. Then there are libraries you add to header path, and library path and something about include and lib folders, but I don't understand those.

A guide from the ground up would help, because I would like to get a better understanding of how it works. I also have no idea what `cmake` is, although I've been seeing it a lot.

Comment: Short answer is just: Build Phases, Link Binary with Libraries, add the framework there. The headers should become available as a result, and the build will link with it. The include usually looks something like #include <SDL2/SDL.h> with a slash. Framework is supposed to get it all in one go.

Comment: My problem is that what happens if they don't have a framework. Do you add include folder to header search path and lib to library search path?

Comment: Exactly so! Directory with .h files to "User search path", and directory with .a files (or other kinds?) to "Library path".

Comment: I hope my [edit](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/96465/2) matches your intention closer. It sounds like you might want to read up on C++ compilation and linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the link process in general, so sorry if I go a bit on a tangent first.

You need to differentiate between object files, static libraries and dynamic libraries. Apple adds "Frameworks" to the mix in OSX. They are just one possible way of adding foreign code into your executable. Roughly speaking:

- Object files (*.o, *.obj) are the result of compiling your source code and become part of the executable (*.exe, *.so, *.dll).
- Static libraries (*.a, *.lib) contain multiple object files and they again become part of your executable. Since the object files of the library are available to the compiler it can perform many optimizations (e.g. removal of unused object files).
- Dynamic libraries are executables without an entry point (main function). Other executables may reference their content at runtime, but that also means their content is not part of those executable files. They can be shared by multiple executables and even unloaded again (e.g. useful for plugins or hardware drivers which should be loaded on demand only).
- Frameworks (*.framework) are just directories that bundle header files, libraries (possibly multiple versions) and other resources (images etc.) together. They're supposed to force a scheme of how the above should be organized to make installation, compilation and linking easier for the programmer. You may find system-wide Frameworks in system folders, but you will also find application-specific ones in App Bundles (*.app).

In case of pre-installed, system-wide Frameworks (e.g. Cocoa) you may assume that they exist on the target machine and just link them, your user will also have them.

SDL and CEGUI are not part of the OS X base system, so it is unlikely that your user installed them system-wide. Therefore you should add such libraries/Frameworks to your App Bundle and link to those local copies, or the application will crash on your users' machines at runtime.

Even if the user installed those Frameworks (unlikely), then the version or configuration might not match. Many developers constantly break the ABI of their library during version updates (due to lack of knowledge, care or use of an ABI-unstable language such as C++). But even if that is not the case the configuration options used during compilation on your users' machines might bite you (e.g. you need GIF image support, but their SDL library was compiled without it). This is called "DLL Hell".

So what to use? People are very religious about static vs dynamic libraries/Frameworks, so you will see very heated debates about this question on forums. In a perfect world we would all use the same library versions and configurations, the dynamic library would only be loaded once and we could all share their memory. In reality this is not the case, and how many of your running applications are using SDL and CEGUI right now anyway? Static libraries also offer the aforementioned optimization possibilities.

So my rough suggestion to you would be:

- Pre-installed system libraries and frameworks (e.g. Cocoa, OpenGL) should be linked dynamically (*.so, *.dll, *.framework). They benefit from system updates (especially security updates).
- Libraries that only your application will use should be put into static libraries and made part of your executable. Dynamic linking and Frameworks are of no advantage here, since you need to distribute them with your application and they will most likely not be shared with other applications.

TL;DR: SDL and CEGUI probably offer both Framework and static library versions. I suggest you use the static library for your application.